# Android: repeat an overflow menu inline with views

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a list of tasks and I want to repeat a menu **inline** within interface **below every item of list,** not as popup or context menu. The reason I'm lookiing for menu instead of a LinearLayout is to easily use "showAsAction" and "ifRoom". Do you have any suggestion?

[image]

What I tried: I have created a **layout/myspecialmenu.xml** and I use addView to include it as a view after each item! Obviously no Success!

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.javacodegeeks.android.menu.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mycontextmenu" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       />
</menu>
```

and this is how I tried to load it after every item programmatically:

```
LinearLayout mymenu=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myspecialmenu);
contents.addView(mymenu);
```

Comment: Did you try with a toolbar ?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html You can put a custom layout and have the menu overflow.

Comment: Toolbar requires API level 21. Is there any solution based on properties of "menu" ?

Comment: I gave you the link of the compatible toolbar from AppCompat_v7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, Just forget the menu implementation.

Go to designer and ask for 3dots icon, keep it in a Button or ImageView. Upon clicking the button, you use [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) to display the view you list options. Set and adapter to ListPopupWindow to create your options.

If you have the options fixed( suppose like 3 options) to show on the linear layout and all the other in the overflow menu, you can easily do it or calculate the width's based on the menu items and move the remaining items to the overflow icon.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. How Do i control the number and display of remaining menu in the popup? totally programmatically without XML?

Comment: if your menu list contains 5 items, Create 3 Views to display in linear layout and the remaining 2 after clicking overflow button. Set the Anchor tag for listpopup as over flow button.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve using `menus` is simply irrelevant. Menus are created when your `Activity` is created. How can you re create menus?

I suggest you the following design:

1) Make a `list_row_item.xml` have a `LinearLayout` horizontal.

2) Insert four items in the horizontal layout; the first 3 being your `TextViews` and the last being an may be an `ImageButton` and give it image of three dots menu.

3) Distribute `weight` among these views accordingly so that `ImageButton` will consume least space on screen.

4) Then you can simple have an OnClickListener on that `ImageButton`.

5) Then again you will want to have `Layout` like the menu, so for that you will need to create a `Fragment` which will be shown when user clicks on `ImageButton`.